# Unable to get output as json dict

Tags: python, django, json

I am getting output as json string with the following code. But I require it as JSON dict without leading and trailing quotes. How can I do that?

It seems to work if I uncomment `line4` but not with raw input.

```
def main(args):
    f = open(args[1], 'w')
    inp = raw_input("Enter a Dict")
    #    inp = {"a":1,"b":2}
    django.utils.simplejson.dumps(inp, f)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    main(sys.argv)
```

sample output I recieve:

```
"{'a':1,'b':2}"
```

output I want:

```
{'a':1,'b':2}
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't print anything at all.  Can you post us the actual working code and its output?

Comment: The output you apparently want is not valid JSON. JSON must have double quotes around keys, not single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input()` returns a string, which is an entirely different object from `inp` which is a Python dictionary.

If you wanted `raw_input` to be treated as JSON, first parse it as such:

```
inp = raw_input("Enter a Dict")
inp = django.utils.simplejson.loads(inp)
django.utils.simplejson.dump(inp, f)
```

or parse it as a Python literal expression:

```
from ast import literal_eval

inp = raw_input("Enter a Dict")
inp = literal_eval(inp)
django.utils.simplejson.dump(inp, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the user's input into a string. It is not a dictionary; it is a string that start with `{` and ends with `}`.

You need to parse/evaluate it as a dictionary first before converting it to json.

```
>>> inp = "{'a': 1, 'b': 2}"
>>> json.dumps(inp)
'"{\'a\': 1, \'b\': 2}"'
>>> import ast
>>> d = ast.literal_eval(inp)
>>> json.dumps(d)
'{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Input = "{'a':1,'b':2}"

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(Input)
```

OR

```
eval(Input)
```

It will work for you...   :)

Output -: {'a':1,'b':2}